# Who was the real life character behind Iroq in Ready Player One?

Tags: character, ready-player-one

Who was the real life character behind Iroq (the one with the hollow skull body) in Ready Player One? I don't mean the actor in real life, but the person in the movie who played the character in virtual reality. For example, the custodian turned out to be the creator's business partner. Did Iroq's real life persona make an appearance in the movie at all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We don't know.  We can suspect that he was a gamer who was sufficiently talented to have been recruited by IOI to help them gain artifacts, kill gunters, and generally do dirty work.

In the book, Irok is at school with Wade and has a smaller part to play in the plot.

We don't find out anything about his/her real persona either in the book or film.

Comment: Oh OK there were so many characters I thought I might have missed something. Everyone else had a 'reveal'. He was my favorite character. I think he was the only one with a sense of humor.